# Calendar.getInstance cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: android, eclipse, calendar, adt

I am trying to read calendar events by specifying the date selection on query.
No matter why I do I get error **"Calendar.getInstance cannot be resolved to a type"** on this line:

```
Calendar c_start= new Calendar.getInstance();
```

This is weird because I do import the java.util.Calendar;

Here is my code

```
package com.authorwjf.calsample;


import java.text.Format;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat; 

import android.util.Log;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.provider.CalendarContract;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.database.Cursor;

import java.util.Calendar;

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.data);
        String title = "N/A";
        Long start = 0L;
        switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.next:
            if(!mCursor.isLast()) mCursor.moveToNext();
            break;
        case R.id.previous:
            if(!mCursor.isFirst()) mCursor.moveToPrevious();
            break;
        }
        Format df = DateFormat.getDateFormat(this);
        Format tf = DateFormat.getTimeFormat(this);
        try {
            title = mCursor.getString(0);
            start = mCursor.getLong(1);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //ignore
        }
        tv.setText(title+" בתאריך "+df.format(start)+" בשעה "+tf.format(start));
    }


}
```

Answer (score 7):

You have to simply change from

```
Calendar c_start= new Calendar.getInstance();
```

to

```
Calendar c_start = Calendar.getInstance();
```

Means you have to just remove `new` keyword.

Answer (score 2):

change your code from..

```
Calendar c_start= new Calendar.getInstance();
```

to

```
Calendar c_start= Calendar.getInstance();
```

because `Calendar.getInstance()` return an object of calendar..

Answer (score 1):

If you are really using this:

```
Calendar c_start= new Calendar.getInstance();
```

Then remove the `new` keyword and it will work

Answer (score 0):

Calendar follow Singleton design patten, then the costructor of the object is called by getInstace() method, this is why you must remove `new` keyword when you instance the object.
Final code : `Calendar c_start = Calendar.getInstance();`